# Do repository sizes increase within time and revisions?

Tags: github, repository

All source code hosting services have size limits. I am wondering that does that mean my files can be up to that size -- or that the repository is limited to that size? Say I have 5 files of 100 kB, if I keep changing them and committing, will the repo size get larger?

For example, Github.com smallest plan has a limit of 0.30 GB, and my project is 50 MB in size -- will I exceed this limit with a lot of revisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repo size gets larger with every commit. But git compresses new files. Your repo does not grow 100kb with a new or changed 100kB file.

I've got a repo with >4000 revisions - it's still smaller than the content itself. 200MB Repo, 250MB files.

Comment: Do you have any figures on how much larger it grows? Can I expect the Github's 0.30 GB limit to be reached any time soon with a project of 50 MB in size?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason for a hosting provider to limit the size of your files (unless you are talking about terabyte-sized monsters). So basically they are talking about the overall size of the repository.

The repo consists of your files and metadata. The way they are stored internally differs for each SCM type.

> For example, Github.com smallest plan has a limit of 0.30 GB, and my project is 50 MB in size -- will I exceed this limit with a lot of revisions?

In fact yes, eventually you will exceed the limit. But Git does its best to store the data as effectively as possible, so it won't happen too early, unless you change the whole project content on each commit.